# How can I define an In-app Billing product in Google Play, what can be purchased multiple times?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to define my In-app Products using Google Play Developer Console.
However when the Add New Product dialog pops up only two options are available, and neither is fit my "can be purchased multiple times" expectation.

- One option is the Managed product, ("... Managed items that can be purchased only once per user account on Google Play...")
- The second is the Subscription, ("... Subscriptions let you sell content, services or features in your app with automated, recurring billing....") Well this is more far what I would like to do.

[image: Managed product]

[image: Subscription]

Answer (score 0):

there is no option to be able to buy an item multiple times per say. What you are looking for is a managed item but when the user uses that item you need to consume that item and then the user can purchase it again.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume